# GCP Cloudbuild Slack bot shared across multiple projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, service-accounts, google-cloud-build

Ive been able to create a slackbot, create a service account, pub/sub and sent notification via CloudRun calling a yaml and json config on a storage bucket, all at project level much like what is done here so that when a successful build occurs we get notified: `https://blog.thecloudside.com/configuring-slack-notifications-for-google-cloud-build-using-cloud-run-2e89323293ab`

however, I have multiple App Engine projects and they all will have the exact same config, do i have to repeat this for all projects ?

or is there a way to create one project called `notification-service` which contains cloudrun, the secrets to the webhook for slackbot and a global org service account so that when any project is built it sends the notification ?

Ive created this but it is not working and Im not sure why at this point, any pointers would be great.

Comment: Create a new project called "notification-service" which will contain the Cloud Run service, secrets for the webhook, and a global org service account.
Create the Cloud Run service in the "notification-service" project using the same configuration as in your previous projects.
Grant the Cloud Run service account permission to publish messages to a Pub/Sub topic in each of the App Engine projects.

Comment: Create a Pub/Sub topic in each of the App Engine projects that you want to monitor.
In each App Engine project, create a Cloud Build trigger that sends a message to the Pub/Sub topic when a build is successful.
In the "notification-service" project, create a subscription for each Pub/Sub topic.
In the Cloud Run service, configure it to read messages from each subscription and send the Slack notification.